# Controlling Border Color using pgfpages

Tags: color, border, pgfpages

pgfpages is a great package for, among many things, creating borders around pages. I am looking for some help to change the color of the border from black to my specified color (\definecolor{my_chosen_blue}{RGB}{54,131,179}). Any suggestions from the community?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{my_chosen_blue}{RGB}{54,131,179}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%

}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\huge\bfseries \textsc{My Title}}\\
 \vspace{.5cm} 
 \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{My_logo.png}\\
 \vspace{1.25cm}
  {\huge\bfseries \textsc{More Title Here}}
 \vspace{2cm}\\
 {\Large\bfseries Subtitle Here}\\
 \hrulefill
 \vspace{3cm}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
Statut du document:&&BROUILLON\\
Version:&&0.1\\
Date:&& le 1$^{ier}$ juin, 2020\\
Classification:&&Confidentiel\\
Destinataire:&&Some Recipient\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Happily, this is pretty easy with your example code:

Just add in `\pgfsetstrokecolor{…}` to your border code:

```
border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfsetstrokecolor{my_chosen_blue}\pgfstroke,%
```

Comment: This did the trick. \pgfsetstrokecolor is described in the 1300-page tikz & pgf manual, but the manual does not present it in the context that I used it. Thanks for bridging the gap David!